# When declaring a variable inside a function, why EVM always pushes 0 before any primitive value onto stack?

Tags: solidity, evm, yul

A simple declaration inside a function such as:

```
uint256 var = 0xffff;
```

has it's line executed in assembly (from Remix) like the following:

```
push0
push1 0xffff
swap1
pop
```

Why was the 0 pushed to be popped later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT:

---

*In Solidity, when a variable is declared and initialized inside a function, the EVM initializes it to the assigned value during runtime. The initialization process might involve pushing the initial value onto the stack, followed by further operations to assign this value to the variable.*

*Regarding the assembly representation you provided:*

***assembly***

- *push0*
- *push1 0xffff*
- *swap1*
- *pop*

*This sequence represents the operations in EVM assembly language. Let's break it down:*

*push0: This opcode pushes a zero onto the stack. In the EVM context, this operation initializes the stack with a default value of zero.*

*push1 0xffff: This opcode pushes the value 0xffff (in hexadecimal, equal to 65535 in decimal) onto the stack. This is the value assigned to the var variable.*

*swap1: This opcode swaps the topmost stack item with the item located at the 1st position from the top of the stack. It's a swapping operation, and in this context, it might be related to rearranging stack elements for further operations or optimizations.*

*pop: This opcode removes the top item from the stack. It might be used for cleanup purposes or as part of optimization in the assembly code.*

***The reason behind pushing a zero (push0) before pushing 0xffff onto the stack might be due to EVM optimization strategies or specific optimizations performed by the Solidity compiler or the Remix tool's assembly output.***

*While the sequence might seem inefficient at first glance (pushing zero to be popped later), EVM assembly can involve various optimizations or stack management strategies that might result in seemingly redundant operations. These operations can sometimes be a result of optimizations, stack rearrangements, or other internal processing in the EVM to efficiently manage the stack and execute the bytecode.*